# mongodb is it possible to get all keys and values of object in documents in the collection?

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to get all keys and values of object in documents in the collection?

I have a collection in mongo db with structure like

```
[{
    _id: '55534c2e2750b4394debedd2',
    selected_options: {
        name: 'test',
        size: 'S',
        color: 'red'
    }
},
 {
    _id: '55534c2e2750b4394debedd3',
    selected_options: {
        name: 'test2',
        size: 'S',
        color: 'red'
    }

},
{
    _id: '55534e087f01fa2a4d30f7f5',
    selected_options: {
        name: 'test3',
        size: 'm',
        color: 'green'
    }
}
........
]
```

how can i get output like :

```
[{
    name: 'name',
    values: ['test', 'test2', 'test3']
},
{
    name: 'size',
    values: ['S', 'm']
},
{
    name: 'color',
    values: ['red', 'green']
}
]
```

Comment: You can achieve this with [**Map-Reduce**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have no option to achieve your result without processing on your client side. However you can try [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/applications/aggregation/) to achieve something similar to your desired output with just a single query.

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate([
                               {$group: 
                                  {
                                     _id: null,
                                     names: {$addToSet: '$selected_options.name'},
                                     sizes: {$addToSet: '$selected_options.size'},
                                     colors: {$addToSet: '$selected_options.color'},
                                  }
                               },
                               {$project:
                                  {_id: 0, names: 1, colors: 1, sizes: 1}
                               }
                           ])
```

This will output the following:

```
{
   names: ['test', 'test2', 'test3'],
   sizes: ['S', 'm'],
   colors: ['red', 'green']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is running a [distinct()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) for each field.

See the example output in the documentation page.